# Put in jQuery SHOW, get error. Pull hair out. (Woocommerce)

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. This is the code I put in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#woo_trigger").click(function(){
$("div#sidebar").hide();
```

});

I get this error in the browser: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

I checked in the header and jQuery is called by default, so Im not sure what the issue is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Include `jquery.js` before this `script` tag.. else check properly whether its loaded or not..

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that 'jQuery is called by default', so I assume that you mean that it is loading correctly. In Wordpress, to use jQuery, you must call your functions a little differently. These are a few ways you can complete this:

```
jQuery("#woo_trigger").click(function(){
  jQuery("div#sidebar").hide();
});
```

You can also use an anonymous function which will map jQuery to `$`:

```
(function($) {
  $("#woo_trigger").click(function(){
    $("div#sidebar").hide();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Or you can also do it this way depending on the need:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#woo_trigger").click(function(){
    $("div#sidebar").hide();
  });
});
```

Here's an excellent article that may help in the future: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/

Comment: You guys are just awesome, seriously. It literally blows me away how helpful and knowledgeable people are. Also makes me realize how far away I am from it. 

When I included jquery before the script tag as  Guruprasad Rao suggested, it worked perfectly. 

What I don't understand now is why the include below was in the header, but it didn't work: 


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.muzcina.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4"></script>

Comment: @Jeff Hmmm... Without seeing the full setup, it's hard to pinpoint exactly why that script 'didn't work'. Did you receive any errors in the console's log when you load your page? You can look at the console by pressing F12 in Chrome, Firefox, IE/Edge (I don't know about Safari or Opera), and then reload your page. Any errors will appear and then you can start debugging.